# Magic Lantern Raw To DNG to where next?

Tags: edit-mode

I've got raw files using Magic Lantern on a Canon 5D Mark II. I've converted them to DNG files then I've converted those DNG files using adobe DNG converter. But I've now don't know how to edit the images?

Is this possible in Blender somehow? At the moment when I go to the image tab to import the images Blender can't see the DNG files what can I do to actually benefit from obtaining raw files?

Comment: I needed to mention it looks like I can drag and drop the images one at a time ? is this incorrect to do?

Comment: As far as I know DNG is  not supported in blender. Use OpenEXR or Tiff with linear encoding instead.